# calculate average of array elements and display them

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The problem is: 
A Class of 40 students has received their grades for 5 exams. Implement a function that calculates the worst average grade and display the the IDs of all students having the worst average grade.‎

I already calculated the average but do not know how to calculate the WORST average ( as in the lowest average of the 40 students) and displaying the ID numbers that have this number.

This is what I have written so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_NUM = 6;
int x[MAX_NUM];
int y[5];

int main()
{


float avg;
float total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter an ID number: " << endl;
    cin >> x[i];
    cout << "Enter 5 grades: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        cin >> y[j];
        while (y[j]>100)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid grade that is less than a 100: " << endl;
            cin >> y[j];
        }
        total += y[j];
    }
        avg = total / 5;

    cout << "ID: " << x[i] << endl;
    cout << "Average: "<< avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean worst average is the lowest average?

Comment: Yes, the worst would be the least

Comment: "worst average"... average is average. Do you mean identify all occurrences of the lowest value?

Comment: @crashmstr: 2d set of points, the he wants the average along each row, and he wants to find the lowest of these averages.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

Note: I have added some important statements!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_NUM = 6;
int x[MAX_NUM];
int y[5];
float AVG[MAX_NUM];
int worstIDCount = 0;

int main()
{


  float avg, min = 1001;
  float total = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
    {
      avg = 0;
      total = 0;
      cout << "Enter an ID number: " << endl;
      cin >> x[i];
      cout << "Enter 5 grades: " << endl;
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      cin >> y[j];
      while (y[j]>100)
        {
          cout << "Please enter a valid grade that is less than a 100: " << endl;
          cin >> y[j];
        }
      total += y[j];
    }
      avg = total / 5;
      AVG[i] = avg;
      if(avg < min)
    min = avg;

      cout << "ID: " << x[i] << endl;
      cout << "Average: "<< avg << endl;
    }
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
    {
      if(AVG[i] == min)
    cout << "Student with WORST Average: ID" << x[i] << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: did you copy the latest edited code? try again! working on my PC!

Comment: It worked now! Thank you so much :)     but can you please explain briefly to me what you did?

Comment: Ok..I created an array of float to store the average of each student (float AVG[MAX_COUNT]) so whenever average of a student is calculated it is stored in the array at respective position and also during the average calculation process I used a "min" variable to find out the least average in the class...did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store these averages in a `std::vector<float>`, `std::sort` it and get the lowest. Then go back and find the students that have that average.

Answer (score 0):

[working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d5bd8ff62c904d4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <functional> // mem_fn
#include <algorithm>  // sort, upper_bound
#include <iterator>   // ostream_iterator

struct Student_average {
  int student_id;
  float average;
};

bool compare_student_averages(Student_average const &lhs,
                              Student_average const &rhs) {
  return lhs.average < rhs.average;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Student_average> averages;

  // collect the data and populate the averages vector
  // ...

  sort(begin(averages), end(averages), compare_student_averages);

  std::cout << "The worst average is: " << averages.front().average << '\n';

  auto end_of_worst_student_averages =
      upper_bound(begin(averages), end(averages), averages.front(),
                  compare_student_averages);

  std::cout << "The IDs of the students with the worst averages are:\n";

  transform(begin(averages), end_of_worst_student_averages,
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
            std::mem_fn(&Student_average::student_id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more C++ way of doing this using `std::accumulate` and `std::min_element` (I removed the check for anything > 100, for brevity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_NUM = 6;
int x[MAX_NUM];
int y[5];

int main()
{
    float avg[5];
    float total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++)
    {
        cin >> x[i];  // ID
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cin >> y[j];  // grades

        // compute the average for this student
        avg[i] = std::accumulate(y, y + 5, 0) / 5.0F;
        cout << "ID: " << x[i] << endl;
        cout << "Average: "<< avg[i] << endl;
    }

    // compute the worst average
    float* worst_average = std::min_element(avg, avg + MAX_NUM);

    // get the position in the array where the worst is found
    int position = std::distance(avg, worst_average);

    // output results
    cout << "This person has the worst average: " << x[position] 
         <<".  The average is " << *worst_average << "\n";
}
```

Note that the averages are stored in an array.  The way the average is computed for each person is to use `std::accumulate` to add up the `y` array values, and then divide by 5.0.

Since we now have the averages in an aray, we want to find the smallest item in the array.  To do that, `min_element` is used to get us the position of where the element is stored.

The trick here is that `min_element` returns a pointer to the smallest item, so we need calculate how far this pointer is located from the beginning of the `avg` array.  To do this, the `std::distance` function is used.  This now gives us the position of the smallest item.

The rest of the code just outputs the results.

As you can see, the only loops involved were the input loops.  The calculation of the average and the worst average were done using `accumulate` and `min_element`, respectively.